# How can I get an encoded string from NSData in Cocoa?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, encoding, byte

In .NET, I can use `Encoding.UTF8.GetString(string str)` or any other flavor of `Encoding`, to get the string representation of a byte array. Does Cocoa contain similar functionality out-of-the-box, or do I need to write some stuff to make the conversions myself?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You use [`initWithData:encoding`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/initWithData:encoding:).  E.g.:

```
[[NSString alloc] initWithData: dataObj encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding]
```

Comment: Thanks--very simple, very elegant!